# Setting a return-path when sending trough Yahoo servers returns error 553

Tags: php, email, pear

I'm using the following code to send the emails and it was working ok

```
    $headers = array (
        'From' => $emailAddress,
        'To' => $emailDest,
            'Subject' => $subject,
            'Return-Path' => 'bounce@*****.eu',
            'X-Codent' => '['.$codent_header.']',
            'X-Ent' => '['.$ent_header.']',
            'X-Bzd' => '['.$database.']',
            'X-Email' => '['.$email['Email'].']'
    );                                      
    $hdrs = $mime->headers($headers, true);

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
        array ('host' => 'ssl://'.$emailServer,
        'auth' => true,
        'port' => '465',
        'username' => $emailUtilizator,
        'password' => $emailParola));

    $mail = $smtp->send($emailDest, $hdrs, $body);
```

However a few days ago the script stopped working when sending trough yahoo. A quick check of the logs revealed the send attempt returned the following error:

```
Failed to set sender: bounce@*****.eu [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 553, response: From address not verified - see http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html)]
```

The script works if I remove the Return-Path but doing so will mean I can't track emails anymore and won't be able to get accurate reports.

The error occurs only when dealing with yahoo. Google, live and other addresses work fine.

Any idea on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking your mail server logs. Find out what the remote (yahoo) mail server does - I think it's trying to verify that the return address is actually valid.

Also make sure that the return address exists and accepts mail.

Comment: thanks, I'll talk to the email server administrator, see what he has to say.